# Iterate a large files of a directory

Tags: java

I have a directory with more than 100,000 files and I need to iterate all of them so i can deal with each file. currentlly i am using this code to read direcory files

```
for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    // TODO
}
```

but there problem in perfermoce,is there a way to do it without taking a lot of time and with memory problemes.

I am using java 11.

Comment: Depends on what `// TODO` actually does, but it's very likely you'll have to find a compromise between memory usage and time taken. You can rarely have both.

Comment: Your performance issue does **not** come from iterating `folder.listFiles()` itself. It is either somewhere else or purely the fact that you process each file sequentially instead of introducing multithreading. In any case, we can not help you with that little detail. Please read [ask]. Voting to close because missing detail.

Answer (score 3):

With the information you provided: You should parallize it and could use java NIO and streams for that. In it's simplest form:

```
Files.list(Path.of("/path/to/dir"))
        .parallel()
        .forEach(path -> {
            // convert it to file if needed, but try to stick with Path and NIO
            var file = path.toFile();
            // TODO
        });
```

If you wan't to exclude some files you also can filter the list first with `Stream::filter`. Since there are no more details available it could be:

- Based on file name:

```
Files.list(Path.of("/path/to/dir"))
                .parallel()
                .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().contains("filterMe"))
                .forEach(path -> {
                    // convert it to file if needed, but try to stick with Path and NIO
                    var file = path.toFile();
                    // TODO
                });
```

- Based on content. In this case it would be more efficient to read the content first. If it is text just map it to `String`:

```
Files.list(Path.of("/path/to/dir"))
        .parallel()
        .map(path -> {
            try {
                return Files.readString(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        })
        .filter(text -> text.contains("filterMe"))
        .forEach(text -> {
            // Todo
        });
```

If the content of the files are in a binary format, you must first process it and map it to an object so java can handle it.

For more details on Javas `Stream API` please see tutorials like that: [Baeldung - The Java 8 Stream API Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams)

Comment: Good answer using streams instead of `File.listFiles()` as this saves a lot of memory as it doesn't have to initially build such a large list. Also, even simpler would be _not_ to convert Path to File, but to operate on Path itself, if possible.

Comment: Good point, I just added the conversion to match the example. But added the recommandation to stick with Path and NIO as comment :)

Comment: We do not know that from the question, but if there are some criteria that exclude some files from `// TODO`, these should be checked with calls to `Stream::filter` to further speed up processing.

Comment: Good point, added information about filter too :)